# How to automatically generate input-array index in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

For example, I have such HTML:

```
<input name="someinput[]">
```

I made a function to clone/remove this input but now I want to assign indexes to name dynamically - when I make an element clones, its new names should be someinput[1], someinput[2] etc. - how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace `[]` with `[index]` using the `attr` callback:

```
var i = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
 $('input:first').clone().attr('name',function(a,e){    
    i++;
    return e.replace("[]","["+i+"]");
 }).insertAfter($('input:last'));
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/c9G7c/

Answer (score 2):

Keep the index of the next input in a global variable, and then use that in your cloning function. Is that what you do?

```
var source = $('#source')
var copy = source.clone().attr('name', 'some[' + index + ']')
$('body').append(copy);
```